# Return view with variable = null if not set in database

Tags: laravel, view, null, return, undefined

i have a question. How can i return view with variable who is null if there is no record in DB.
i know return $variable ?? null;
but i need this in a view.

```
public function shop_items($shelf)
{
    $shop_shelf = $this->getTreeItems(0);
    $shop_items = DB::table("shop_items")->where('shelf_id', $shelf)->get();
    return view('shop',compact('shop_items','shop_shelf'));
}
```

if there is record i get the valeu of $shop_items but if there is no such record got Undefined offset: 0

edite:
 add shop.blade

```
@if(isset($shop_shelf))
@foreach($shop_shelf as $ss)
    <ul>
        <li>{{$ss["title"]}}
            @if(is_array($ss["children"]))
                <ul>
                    @foreach($ss["children"] as $sc)
                        <li>
                            <a href="/shop/shelf/{{$sc["id"]}}">
                                {{$sc["title"]}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWVPq.png)

could not post all code so i put an image of shop.blade

Comment: could you add your shop.blade.php code ?

Comment: Please can you show where you're using `$shop_items`.

Comment: i added it in an image. culdnt copy all code. to long for post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
@forelse($shop_shelf as $ss)
    <ul>
        <li>{{$ss["title"]}}
            @if(is_array($ss["children"]))
                <ul>
                    @foreach($ss["children"] as $sc)
                        <li>
                            <a href="/shop/shelf/{{$sc["id"]}}">
                                {{$sc["title"]}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    </ul>
@empty
    <p>No data to display</p>
@endforelse
```

> PS : apply the @forelse loop structure wherever you have an `array` in
>   your blade

See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops)

Comment: i have problem with the second code where is $shop_items used. need to look at the image. becouse cold not post it here, to long

Comment: PS : apply the @forelse loop structure wherever you have an array in your blade

Comment: $shop_items is a sting for me.

Comment: from the image i uploaded

Comment: @AndrisVelps Glad I could help! If this has answered your question please may you marked it as accepted :) Thanks